# Eigen values of A*A are non negatives.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a complex matrix of order $n$ then i like to prove that all eigen values of $A*A$ are non negative where $*$ is transpose conjugate .

$ \lambda \|x\|^2 = \langle \lambda x,x \rangle = \langle A^*A x,x\rangle = \langle Ax,Ax \rangle \ge 0$ so eigen values of $A*A$ are non negative.But i like to prove this result without using inner product i.e. just by assuming definition of eigen value and some basic linear algebra . But did not get the answer. Please solve it thanks in advance.

Comment: If we get rid of the inner product, are we still allowed to take the "conjugate transpose"?

Comment: But, in truth, the definition of $A^*$ is based on an inner product, so this is the most natural proof.

Comment: how conjagate transpose is based on inner product ?

Comment: A common definition of the adjoint $A^*$ (which turns out to be the conjugate-transpose for matrices) is that $A^*$ is *defined* to be the unique linear transformation satisfying
$$
\langle Ax,y \rangle = \langle x,A^*y \rangle
$$
for all vectors $x,y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to *just* conjugate transpose, you can note that
$$
\lambda \|x\|^2 = \lambda x^*x = (Ax)^*(Ax) = x^*(A^*A)x
$$
If you want to **actually** avoid inner products, you'll need to be very careful about what exactly you mean by $A^*$.